# Cannot call value of non-function type 'module<MyFramework>'

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

I did a Swift 3 framework and now I'd like to test it in a sample application. To do that, firstly, I **built it**, I **dropped it** into my sample application, I **linked it** to the required binaries and frameworks and I **added** `import MyFramwork` into my source file.

That works well ... only if the target is 'Generic iOS Device'. If I select something else, like 'iPhone 7', there are an error :

`cannot call value of non-function type 'module<MyFramework>'`

... when I call my class constructor :

`let myClassHandler = myFrameworkClass(value1: "Foo", value2: "bar")`

I don't have any idea about the source of the problem and I found nothing about it on internet.

I'll appreciate any idea about that, thanks :)

---

#### EDIT :

If I put the xcodeproj file WITH the Framework link, it works. But if I only include my Framework. I get the previous error. I can't give my Framework source code to our customers so I can't include xcodeproj file.

Comment: Same problem I'm facing. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I didn't found the solution yet. I added the entire framework xcodeproj file to my sample application for the moment

Comment: Did anyone find any solution? I need to give this framework to users but apparently i cant give now. I cant share my source code. Any help?

Comment: I am also facing this issue, and no idea what I've done wrong. Followed the steps from multiple sources, including Apple's own documentation, and no idea what I've done wrong.